# Adding SSL on a single Page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want 'only' my Login page to be SSL enabled. When the user logsin using https://mysite.login.aspx, after the login the user should be taken to an http://mysite.default.aspx

Please tell me step by step how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's a Step by Step Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998310.aspx) for you!

[Try out this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998310.aspx) for Self-Signed SLL Certs. Using IIS 7

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the advice from Filip, you may also be interested in a free http module that will allow you to require that certain pages or folders be secure.  So if the user tries to access your login page without SSL they will be automatically redirected to the secure version.  The module is easy to configure which might come in handy if you find that other pages should require security as well.

See the details and download the source/binary at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/WebPageSecurity_v2.aspx)